# railstutorial chapter 9 limit user access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

i followed the tutorial in railstutorial.org. I noticed that if i use the url
localhost:3000/users/102

logged in or out, i can view the profile. If i change the 102 to another existing user i can also view it. How can i limit the access to this page? I want that only the current user can be able to view his/her profile.

I am new at rails.

i know its got to do something with users_controller.erb in the code

```
def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 3):

This does depend on how you define your current_user helper. For instance, if you were using Devise for authentication, it would be `if current_user == @user`, but I believe for the helper on that tutorial, the method below should work.

```
def show
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   if current_user?(@user)
      # show page
   else
      # render error page?
      flash[:error] = "Nope" # Clearly here you can do whatever you want, from error pages to redirections
      redirect_to root_path
   end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

seems like the right solution would be to add another function

at the top it would be

```
before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
before_action :correct_user_return,   only: [:show]
```

and then in the private section it would be

```
def correct_user_return
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to current_user unless current_user?(@user)
end
```